# Does Presto support HDP2 High Availability configuration?

Tags: hadoop, hive, high-availability, presto

I have set up 5 data node cluster over 2 namenodes which is configured for high availability in my Hadoop 2.6.0 cluster. My Presto configuration is based on 1 Co-ordinator node and 3 worker nodes.

I had been querying from presto using hive metastore when my cluster was a single namenode cluster. But now after configuring for HA, I am having issues accessing my hdfs using presto like given below :

```
Query 20150320_120620_00004_vgrag failed: java.net.UnknownHostException: mycluster
```

where mycluster is the combination of both the namenodes(active and standby). Can anyone help me resolve this error. Or at least someone tell me if presto supports a HA Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem (although I'm using CDH), and in my case it helped to add this entry to `etc/catalog/hive.properties` :

`hive.config.resources=/etc/hadoop/conf/core-site.xml,/etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml`

(as suggested in presto's [documentation](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html))